# Drawing polylines with specific angles in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

is it possible to add a specific angles to polyline in QT?

i draw a polyline with:

```
 QPointF points[3] = {      
     QPointF(x,y),
     QPointF(x2,y2};
     QPointF(x3,y3};
     painter.drawPolyline(points, 3);
```

I need a polyline with an arrow at the end. My Idea was that i copy the last line part, reduce his size and give him an specific angle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible, I can only suggest you to look at the [Analog Clock](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/coordsys.html) example on the documentation to see how to draw a rotated arrow.